# Track only child process's heap and stack usage

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a parent process which forks and [`execve`](http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man2/execve.2.html) a child process. I wish to track only the peak heap and stack usage of the child. Can someone tell me how?

I thought of using

```
valgrind --tool=massif --track-child=yes prog
```

but the report generated by massif contains memory information of the parent also. I am only interested in the child and that too the peak usage (heap and stack separately)

I am trying to do this on Linux.

Comment: You should avoid text walls. Code should be formatted. Read the help, its quite short.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a somewhat manual way of doing things. I might fill the heap and stack with predetermined test values, before the child calls exec().  This way, you can look back at the stack and heap in order to check what values changed.  Is this what you're looking for, or do you want to monitor the stack and heap as they change dynamically?

Comment: When the child calls execve(), the memory map will be replaced. So I need to do it after child calls execve(). Also, I would like to have a tool do it so that its more faster and reliable I suppose. I can try this solution as a last resort I suppose. Also, I am not sure how malloc uses heap. It reserves more heap than it uses. I would like to find the total heap taken by malloc and not just the heap that the application actually use.